# Flip DDS Texture without original source image for OpenGL

Tags: opengl, dds

I'm wondering if there's a converter for DDS textures after they've been created. We don't have access to the original source images and we would like to avoid changing our shaders, as I'm told it's less efficient to flip them during runtime. Also we don't want the added load time of flipping them. Does anything like that exist? I couldn't find it if there is...

Comment: Yeah, there's something like a 3 day waiting period in which you can't mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this one originally, but NVidia has the DDS Utilities Legacy Texture Tool - https://developer.nvidia.com/legacy-texture-tools.

Specify the -flip option and walla! good to go...

EDIT: the only downside to this is that it tends to increase the size of textures unnecessarily, changing some from DXT1 to DXT5, and there doesn't seem to be a way to match the output texture type to the input texture type. So it looks like I might have to write a tool to read the type and pass that through the command line...

Answer (score 1):

If you have Adobe Photoshop, you could use the Nvidia Texture Tools for Adobe Photoshop: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-texture-tools-adobe-photoshop

It gives you a bit more control over your textures, and you can even edit dds textures this way.